# An error with io.read() in lua

Tags: lua, scite

When I use `io.read()` I get input from the user but when I do so it wont count backspaces, so if I type:

```
blah blah blaht
```

when my program wants input then if I delete the **t**:

```
blah blah blah
```

It still reads it as if the **t** is there, help?

EDIT: Only does this when debugging, im using SciTE, thx

Comment: Yes, it runs incorrectly in SciTE.

Comment: Is there still a problem? If so what would you like to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and I came across this:

> You have two programs here: SciTE and cmd. SciTE sends each visible
>   character like 'r' through to cmd as soon as it is typed. ScITE
>   interprets the backspace key internally to change the buffer but does
>   not send the key through to cmd. You can not edit a command line as
>   you want. Simplest to type Enter and try again. [(source)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scite-interest/mwPMKwURmMY)

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to fix this.

Your best options are:

1. Execute the Lua script outside of SciTE and then you wont have this issue
2. Use another editor